# Return custom response in websocket in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, websocket

I wanted to return a response if the token is invalid.

- **consumer.py**

```
some code...

async def connect(self):
        try:
            self.userId = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['token']

            try:
                UntypedToken(self.userId)
            except (InvalidToken, TokenError) as e:
                print(e)
                return {"response": False, "return_code": "invalid_token", "result": {}, "message": errors["token_not_valid"]}

some code...
```

in a browser, I'm not getting error details. I'm using [WebSocket Test Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/websocket-test-client/fgponpodhbmadfljofbimhhlengambbn?hl=en).
and in postman, I'm getting this

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000
Handshake Details
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/users/eyJ0e.eyJ0b2In0.cbyYygG/chat/
Request Method: GET
Request Headers
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: RpWsJRu+ziCUjwLtRjgNHg==
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
```

- a result I'm expecting is.

```
{
    "response": false,
    "return_code": "invalid_token",
    "result": {},
    "message": "token error"
}
```

Comment: My advice, Firstly check how WebSocket work, in WebSocket is bidirectional network, so you can't return, rather you can send message also to client.

Comment: If it's any security issue, I would do this in REST, not Socket

Comment: Yes, I got it if I will connected and after sometime when the token is invalid so I should send kind of flag like token_is_expire = False or Ture